# dbt.exceptions has no attribute DatabaseException?

Tags: dbt

I am receiving an error for a dbt model that has never had any previous issues. The error that appears details that module dbt.exceptions has no attribute database exception?

I am on dbt-core using the dbt-sqlserver adapter, and have never encountered this error. I have tried a dbt clean -> dbt deps -> dbt run and still have not solved the issue. I only started encountering this error after I upgraded to 1.4.1 and am wondering if that may have started causing this issue to surface?

Comment: You need to include the full error and more details about your installation (e.g., a Pipfile, pip list, packages.yml, etc.), or we're just guessing. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [dbt-sqlserver](https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-sqlserver/releases) hasn't released 1.4 yet, so your dbt-core version is ahead of your adapter version. You should never install dbt-core separately from your adapter, or pin a specific version of core. If you just `pip install dbt-sqlserver`, it will install a compatible version of dbt-core.

Comment: This is not strictly true. When I installed `dbt-sqlserver==1.3.1` the dependencies were incorrectly pegged to `dbt-core==1.5.0` and it created this same error. The maintainer of the `dbt-sqlserver` project is not building their package correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The maintainer of `dbt-sqlserver` has made the following mistake in their `setup.py` file:

```
install_requires=[
    "dbt-core>=1.3.0"
],
```

This means that `dbt-sqlserver` (which is currently at v1.3.1) will always install the incorrect version of `dbt-core` (which is currently ahead at v1.5.0).

The solution is to forcibly install `dbt-core==1.3.1` (or whatever version you want, just as long as it matches the version you're using for `dbt-sqlserver`).

Potentially you may also need to use a package manager like `pipenv`, which will ensure that your dependencies align (I've had issues with `pip` alone not retrieving the correct package dependencies for this exact install).

You may also want to ensure that you're running Python 3.10 or lower, since `dbt-sqlserver` does not currently claim to support Python 3.11.